# Como saber si un correo ha sido leido

Tags: c#, email

Hola amigos quiero hacer un mail masivo y quiero saber:

- Cuantas personas leyeron el correo que envié.

Comment: Hola Wozzie. La pregunta [es demasiada amplia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Te invito a repasar [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si envias el mail usando codigo deberias asignar:

```
mail.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "direccionmail@dominio.com"):
```

de esta forma quien reciba el mail podra enviar un acuse de recibo.

Tambien podrias evaluar asignar la propiedad

[MailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.deliverynotificationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

No vas a conocer cuantas personas leyeron el mail de una forma directa, pero si podras recibir las nodificaciones de quienes lo hicieron y por lo tanto tener ese registro.